# Linked Lists C Deleting Node

Tags: c, list

I'm just starting to learn linked lists and i was practicing by writing some basic functions such as add or delete. The program was working for some time but then i guess i did something and it starting giving me segmentation fault at my delete function which is this. The segmentation fault is in the while loop in if. Any idea why? Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english :).

```
void deleteNode(struct node **first, int age)    
{

    struct node *tempNode;
    if((*(*first)).age == age)
    {
        tempNode = *first;
        *first = (*first)->next;
        free(tempNode);
    }

    struct node *currentNode = (*first)->next;
    struct node *lastNode = *first;

    while(currentNode!=NULL)
    {
        //Segmentation Fault
        if(currentNode->age == age)
        {
            tempNode = currentNode;
            lastNode->next = currentNode->next;
            free(tempNode);
        }
        lastNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the last 2 lines where i change the previous and the current node.

Comment: few lines above you've `free`d it through `tempNode = currentNode; free(tempNode).` now you are trying to get `next` from the free memory.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are referencing `lastNode` after it has been freed.  If we look at the trace of the loop, you free `tempNode`, which you have assigned to `currentNode`, and then you set `lastNode` to `currentNode`.  You want `lastNode` to point to the last valid node, so the update `lastNode = currentNode` is only valid if `currentNode` has not been freed.

In short, the fix is to only assign `lastNode = currentNode` if you *don't* remove the current node.

Answer (score 0):

The trick with freeing nodes from a list is to get the information out of the node before you free it. Attempting to access memory that has been freed results in undefined behavior.

In this case you are only dealing with `next`, and you are tracking `lastNode`. So, `lastNode->next` is the logical `currentNode`.

In the beginning of your function, you account for the case that the `first` node matches `age`. However, if that is the case, the next node may also match `age`. So, your `first` matches `age` case also needs to be a loop.

Instead of writing two loops, use the concept of *address of previous node's next* to represent `lastNode`. This works well since `first` is already a pointer to a pointer to `node`.

```
struct node **lastNode = first;

while (*lastNode != NULL) {
    struct node *currentNode = *lastNode;
    if (currentNode->age != age) {
        lastNode = &currentNode->next;
        continue;
    }
    /* remove currentNode */
    *lastNode = currentNode->next;
    free(currentNode);
}
```